# How to get the time of each audio sample

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

so from my understanding is that the mediarecorder saves audio samples and binds them with a timeStamp to be able to seek through the audio file later (by the help of a prgressbar):

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    recorder.start();
```

**My question**

- Is there any way to get these timestamps of audio samples real time while recording a voice?

please I need your help.